# Error when using Custom Style for TextView

Tags: android, layout

I am currently defining a custom theme that is to be used in an Android app. My style definitions are as follows:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorLightGreen500</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorAmber900</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorLightGreen700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAmber200</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorLightGreen100</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorLightGreen600</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorLightGreen400</item>

    <item name="planesToolbarForegroundColor">@color/colorAmber200</item>
    <item name="planesToolbarBackgroundColor">@color/colorLightGreen400</item>
    <item name="planesBackgroundStartColor">@color/colorAmber500</item>
    <item name="planesBackgroundEndColor">@color/colorLightGreen700</item>
    <item name="planesGameButtonBackgroundColor">@color/colorLightGreen700</item>
    <item name="planesGameButtonHighlightedBackgroundColor">@color/colorLightGreenA700</item>
    <item name="planesGameButtonForegroundColor">@color/colorAmber100</item>
    <item name="planesTextColor">@color/colorAmber700</item>
    <item name="planesNavigationMenuTextColor">@color/colorAmberA100</item>
    <item name="planesNavigationMenuBackgroundColor">@color/colorLightGreen400</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTextViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">?planesTextColor</item>
</style>
```

I have the following layout using this style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/popup_help_title"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         style="@style/CustomTextViewStyle"
         android:text="@string/help"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_help_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_help_title"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/popup_help_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:text="@string/popup_help_button_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_help_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When inflating this layout I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5:     TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040323 a=6}
                                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:596)
                                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3961)
```

Can anyone please explain how can I fix this problem ?

I need to mention here that this layout is inflated as a popup as follows:

```
val inflater =
           m_Context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as    LayoutInflater
    val popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help_popup, null)
```

The context is obtained as follows:

```
 val helpPopup = HelpPopup(applicationContext, m_MainLayout, mSelectedItem, ::startTutorialFragment)
```

When I am using this style in a fragment layout inflated as follows it works:

```
binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Comment: It works when in the style I use directly one of the colors defined in colors.xml. But I would like to have a fully customizable app style and I would like use the colors defined in the theme in the TextViewCustomStyle. I mention that the style I am using is working perfectly in the fragment layouts. The layout code I have given is being inflated manually to appear as a popup. I am updating my question with the related information.

Comment: How are you assigning `m_Context`? That is, where'd you get that `Context`?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It was the applicationContext which as I found out does not work properly with layout inflating. I have corrected the issue. I am updating the question and you can post an answer if you wish.

Comment: No problem. I'm good, though. Nothin' huge. Please feel free to finish this up however you'd like. I've actually answered this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55766752), if that might have some new info for ya, or if you'd wanna use it as a duplicate target, or whatever. Thanks, though. Glad I could help. Cheers!